# Program.Main(string[])' has the wrong signature to be an entry point Format For Project

Tags: c#

I have a warning and an error in Microsoft Visual studio 2019.  Everything was working just fine and this seemed to pop up out of no where.

Main is defined as:

```
 static object Main(string[] args)
```

But I am getting this whilst trying to compile:

> Warning    CS0028  'Program.Main(string[])' has the wrong signature to be an entry point   Format For Project
>
> Error  CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point Format For Project

Comment: Main must return int oder void (or Task if async)

Comment: Why do you want to return object from Main? Are you trying to achieve something specific?

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of possible signatures for the entry point in to a C# program. Unfortunately `static object Main(string[] args)` is not one of them.

I'd say your most likely candidate is either

```
static int Main(string[] args)
```

Or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

For more info checkout [Main Method in C# on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/main-method-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: I'd advise NOT making your entry point return int. If you need to exit your program with non-zero return codes, use the Environment static class.

Answer (score 1):

Main method should have return type int or void (or maybe something else also, but those are common), not object.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{}
```